# SUBSONIC using subcommander via VS2008 causing following errors - help please

Tags: vb.net, .net-3.5, subsonic, subsonic3, subsonic2.2

Ive been using subcommander to generate my dal.  Im using vb.net and sqlexpress and .net 3.5

My webconfig looks like this

```
<!-- add subsonic in for dal-->
    <section name="SubSonicService" type="SubSonic.SubSonicSection, SubSonic" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" requirePermission="false"/>
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>

    <!-- Development connection string -->
    <add name="kimconnection" connectionString="Data Source=7NQ384J\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=kim2;Integrated Security=True;"/>
</connectionStrings>

<!--Add my provider for subsonic to my database-->
<SubSonicService defaultProvider="kimAppProvider">
    <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="kimAppProvider" type="SubSonic.SqlDataProvider, SubSonic" connectionStringName="kimconnection" generatedNamespace="kimdata"/>
    </providers>
</SubSonicService>
<appSettings>


<!--Add my provider for generating my dal / classes-->
<buildProviders>
    <add extension=".abp" type="SubSonic.BuildProvider, SubSonic"/>
</buildProviders>
```

Ok my problem is that if I comment out my build provider (as I thought I didnt use it when using subcommander to generate my classes), I cant do imports kimdata inside my aspx code behinds to access to classes.

However if I leave this is, (ie dont comment it out) and I then debug my code in visual studio I get over 200 errors, the error message is "statement cannot appear outside method body"

the error seems to show this im my compiled app_code when its debugging, the thing is this is c#, im using vb, the classes I generate are vb, and the default language is vb, so why is this in c# and is this the reason im getting the errors? or is there some other reason, and how can I resolve this as my app wont run as there are to many erorrs,

```
#ExternalChecksum("d:\dscott\windows\Visual Studio 2008\WebSites\KimV2\App_Code\builder.abp","{406ea660-64cf-4c82-b6f0-42d48172a799}","ECAA88F7FA0BF610A5A26CF545DCD3AA")
using System; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration; 
using System.Xml; 
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using SubSonic; 
using SubSonic.Utilities;

namespace kimdata
{
 /// <summary>
 /// Strongly-typed collection for the AlertMessage class.
 /// </summary>
    [Serializable]
 public partial class AlertMessageCollection : ActiveList<AlertMessage, AlertMessageCollection>
 {    
  public AlertMessageCollection() {}

        /// <summary>
  /// Filters an existing collection based on the set criteria. This is an in-memory filter
  /// Thanks to developingchris for this!
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>AlertMessageCollection</returns>
  public AlertMessageCollection Filter()
        {
            for (int i = this.Count - 1; i > -1; i--)
            {
                AlertMessage o = this[i];
                foreach (SubSonic.Where w in this.wheres)
                {
                    bool remove = false;
                    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pi = o.GetType().GetProperty(w.ColumnName);
                    if (pi.CanRead)
                    {
                        object val = pi.GetValue(o, null);
                        switch (w.Comparison)
                        {
                            case SubSonic.Comparison.Equals:
                                if (!val.Equals(w.ParameterValue))
                                {
                                    remove = true;
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (remove)
                    {
                        this.Remove(o);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return this;
        }


 }
 /// <summary>
 /// This is an ActiveRecord class which wraps the alertMessages table.
 /// </summary>
 [Serializable]
 public partial class AlertMessage : ActiveRecord<AlertMessage>, IActiveRecord
 {
  #region .ctors and Default Settings

  public AlertMessage()
  {
    SetSQLProps();
    InitSetDefaults();
    MarkNew();
  }

  private void InitSetDefaults() { SetDefaults(); }

  public AlertMessage(bool useDatabaseDefaults)
  {
   SetSQLProps();
   if(useDatabaseDefaults)
    ForceDefaults();
   MarkNew();
  }

  public AlertMessage(object keyID)
  {
   SetSQLProps();
   InitSetDefaults();
   LoadByKey(keyID);
  }

  public AlertMessage(string columnName, object columnValue)
  {
   SetSQLProps();
   InitSetDefaults();
   LoadByParam(columnName,columnValue);
  }

  protected static void SetSQLProps() { GetTableSchema(); }

  #endregion

  #region Schema and Query Accessor 
  public static Query CreateQuery() { return new Query(Schema); }
  public static TableSchema.Table Schema
  {
   get
   {
    if (BaseSchema == null)
     SetSQLProps();
    return BaseSchema;
   }
  }

  private static void GetTableSchema() 
  {
   if(!IsSchemaInitialized)
   {
    //Schema declaration
    TableSchema.Table schema = new TableSchema.Table("alertMessages", TableType.Table, DataService.GetInstance("kimAppProvider"));
    schema.Columns = new TableSchema.TableColumnCollection();
    schema.SchemaName = @"dbo";
    //columns

    TableSchema.TableColumn colvarMessageID = new TableSchema.TableColumn(schema);
    colvarMessageID.ColumnName = "messageID";
    colvarMessageID.DataType = DbType.Int32;
    colvarMessageID.MaxLength = 0;
    colvarMessageID.AutoIncrement = true;
    colvarMessageID.IsNullable = false;
    colvarMessageID.IsPrimaryKey = true;
    colvarMessageID.IsForeignKey = false;
    colvarMessageID.IsReadOnly = false;
    colvarMessageID.DefaultSetting = @"";
    colvarMessageID.ForeignKeyTableName = "";
    schema.Columns.Add(colvarMessageID);

    TableSchema.TableColumn colvarDocumentType = new TableSchema.TableColumn(schema);
    colvarDocumentType.ColumnName = "documentType";
    colvarDocumentType.DataType = DbType.AnsiString;
    colvarDocumentType.MaxLength = 50;
    colvarDocumentType.AutoIncrement = false;
    colvarDocumentType.IsNullable = false;
    colvarDocumentType.IsPrimaryKey = false;
    colvarDocumentType.IsForeignKey = false;
    colvarDocumentType.IsReadOnly = false;
    colvarDocumentType.DefaultSetting = @"";
    colvarDocumentType.ForeignKeyTableName = "";
    schema.Columns.Add(colvarDocumentType);

    TableSchema.TableColumn colvarMessageTitle = new TableSchema.TableColumn(schema);
    colvarMessageTitle.ColumnName = "messageTitle";
    colvarMessageTitle.DataType = DbType.AnsiString;
    colvarMessageTitle.MaxLength = 200;
    colvarMessageTitle.AutoIncrement = false;
    colvarMessageTitle.IsNullable = false;
    colvarMessageTitle.IsPrimaryKey = false;
    colvarMessageTitle.IsForeignKey = false;
    colvarMessageTitle.IsReadOnly = false;
    colvarMessageTitle.DefaultSetting = @"";
    colvarMessageTitle.ForeignKeyTableName = "";
    schema.Columns.Add(colvarMessageTitle);

    TableSchema.TableColumn colvarMsgPublishDate = new TableSchema.TableColumn(schema);
    colvarMsgPublishDate.ColumnName = "msgPublishDate";
    colvarMsgPublishDate.DataType = DbType.DateTime;
    colvarMsgPublishDate.MaxLength = 0;
    colvarMsgPublishDate.AutoIncrement = false;
    colvarMsgPublishDate.IsNullable = false;
    colvarMsgPublishDate.IsPrimaryKey = false;
    colvarMsgPublishDate.IsForeignKey = false;
    colvarMsgPublishDate.IsReadOnly = false;
    colvarMsgPublishDate.DefaultSetting = @"";
    colvarMsgPublishDate.ForeignKeyTableName = "";
    schema.Columns.Add(colvarMsgPublishDate);

    TableSchema.TableColumn colvarXml = new TableSchema.TableColumn(schema);
    colvarXml.ColumnName = "xml";
    colvarXml.DataType = DbType.String;
    colvarXml.MaxLength = 1073741823;
    colvarXml.AutoIncrement = false;
    colvarXml.IsNullable = false;
    colvarXml.IsPrimaryKey = false;
    colvarXml.IsForeignKey = false;
    colvarXml.IsReadOnly = false;
    colvarXml.DefaultSetting = @"";
    colvarXml.ForeignKeyTableName = "";
    schema.Columns.Add(colvarXml);

    TableSchema.TableColumn colvarCreatedOn = new TableSchema.TableColumn(schema);
    colvarCreatedOn.ColumnName = "createdOn";
    colvarCreatedOn.DataType = DbType.DateTime;
    colvarCreatedOn.MaxLength = 0;
    colvarCreatedOn.AutoIncrement = false;
    colvarCreatedOn.IsNullable = false;
    colvarCreatedOn.IsPrimaryKey = false;
    colvarCreatedOn.IsForeignKey = false;
    colvarCreatedOn.IsReadOnly = false;
    colvarCreatedOn.DefaultSetting = @"";
    colvarCreatedOn.ForeignKeyTableName = "";
    schema.Columns.Add(colvarCreatedOn);

    TableSchema.TableColumn colvarCreatedBy = new TableSchema.TableColumn(schema);
    colvarCreatedBy.ColumnName = "createdBy";
    colvarCreatedBy.DataType = DbType.String;
    colvarCreatedBy.MaxLength = 50;
    colvarCreatedBy.AutoIncrement = false;
    colvarCreatedBy.IsNullable = false;
    colvarCreatedBy.IsPrimaryKey = false;
    colvarCreatedBy.IsForeignKey = false;
    colvarCreatedBy.IsReadOnly = false;
    colvarCreatedBy.DefaultSetting = @"";
    colvarCreatedBy.ForeignKeyTableName = "";
    schema.Columns.Add(colvarCreatedBy);

    TableSchema.TableColumn colvarModifiedOn = new TableSchema.TableColumn(schema);
    colvarModifiedOn.ColumnName = "modifiedOn";
    colvarModifiedOn.DataType = DbType.DateTime;
    colvarModifiedOn.MaxLength = 0;
    colvarModifiedOn.AutoIncrement = false;
    colvarModifiedOn.IsNullable = true;
    colvarModifiedOn.IsPrimaryKey = false;
    colvarModifiedOn.IsForeignKey = false;
    colvarModifiedOn.IsReadOnly = false;
    colvarModifiedOn.DefaultSetting = @"";
    colvarModifiedOn.ForeignKeyTableName = "";
    schema.Columns.Add(colvarModifiedOn);

    TableSchema.TableColumn colvarModifiedBy = new TableSchema.TableColumn(schema);
    colvarModifiedBy.ColumnName = "modifiedBy";
    colvarModifiedBy.DataType = DbType.String;
    colvarModifiedBy.MaxLength = 50;
    colvarModifiedBy.AutoIncrement = false;
    colvarModifiedBy.IsNullable = true;
    colvarModifiedBy.IsPrimaryKey = false;
    colvarModifiedBy.IsForeignKey = false;
    colvarModifiedBy.IsReadOnly = false;
    colvarModifiedBy.DefaultSetting = @"";
    colvarModifiedBy.ForeignKeyTableName = "";
    schema.Columns.Add(colvarModifiedBy);

    BaseSchema = schema;
    //add this schema to the provider
    //so we can query it later
    DataService.Providers["kimAppProvider"].AddSchema("alertMessages",schema);
   }
  }
  #endregion

  #region Props

  PK Collections

        #endregion

        #region Deep Save

        #endregion
 }
}
```

Any help or advice greatly appreciated.

Dan

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have to tell subsonic which code language to use for code generation.
If you use subcommander you can add a `/lang vb` parameter to the command line. If you use the build provider I am 95% certain subsonic will choose the right language to use by itself. One possible mistake you made is that, according to the docs: http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Setting_up_SubSonic_2.x the buildprovider section has to be inside a compilation tag:

```
<compilation debug="true" defaultLanguage="C#">
      <!--########################## SubSonic Build Provider ###############################-->
      <!--This will NOT WORK in Medium Trust-->
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".abp" type="SubSonic.BuildProvider, SubSonic"/>
      </buildProviders>
```

You should create one for yourself with

```
    <compilation debug="true" defaultLanguage="VB">
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Everyone and thanks for your answers, however i tried all of these previously and couldnt get it to work, luckily i have now fixed the issue.

I did this by creating my own class vb class library, adding the reference system.web, system.configuration, subsonic.dll and associated dlls, i then added an app config with my connection string and service provider and then generated my classes, i then built the class as a dll.

I included the DLL inside my website bin folder and now everything compiles and works fine.

However this does now mean i have to reference my dal as kimDal.kimdata but hey it works so im please

Thanks to all

dan